# how to fetch items from varien_db_select to collection

Tags: magento-1.9, query

What is the proper way to fetch items from custom made flat model, from `varien_db_select` instance?

Like this:

```
    $col = Mage::getModel('Module/contact_request')->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToSelect(array('entity_id', 'update', 'status'))
                ->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $productId)
                ->getSelect()
                ->order('update DESC'); // $col is varien_db_select instance
```

All `model` and `resourceModel` init files are plain simply with `_construct`s

`Company_Model_Model_Resource_Contact_Request` extends `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract` so it is basic flat model as it is.

I found basic solution as:

```
 $rawQuery = $col->__toString();
        $connection = Mage::getResourceModel('core/resource')->getReadConnection('core_read');
        $requestContact = $connection->fetchAll($rawQuery);
```

But is it how it should be ?

**UPDATE**

That was simply enough but a bit tricky for me, according to Marius answer it was just required to separate `getSelect()->order()` from collection as following:

```
    $col = Mage::getModel('Module/contact_request')->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToSelect(array('entity_id', 'update', 'status'))
                ->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $productId);

    $col =      ->getSelect()
                ->order('update DESC');
```

and then `$col` will be collection object instead of `varien_db_select`

Comment: did u  create module,model ?

Comment: yes, this is custom flat model

Comment: please share ur  module

Comment: Amit, it is big, what part of it should i share? `config.xml` ? `model`, `resourceModel`  they are all empty simply with `_construct`s?

Comment: yes sure and share at github etc open source storage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need to run the query manually.
You can do this:

```
$col = Mage::getModel('Module/contact_request')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToSelect(array('entity_id', 'update', 'status'))
            ->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $productId);

$col->getSelect()
            ->order('update DESC');
```

Then just loop through `$col`.

```
foreach ($col as $item)
{
    //do something with $item
}
```

Comment: Thank you Marius I have seen this before and fore some strange reason it does not work for me, `$col` is always of `Varien_Db_Select` type, `count($col)` is always `1` and as I had briefly explore upcasting it does not implement any of `ArrayAccess` or similar interfaces - `Varien_Db_Select -> Zend_Db_Select`, but i had not dig into the magic methods.  Maybe this is just because this is simply custom created model ? Weird stuff anyway, so I just had to go back to  `Mage::getResourceModel('core/resource')` approach, hope it's doesnt affect the performance...

Comment: Ah I see !!! I should just separate `getSelect` in another variable operation, and then I get my collection object instead of `varien_db_select` !!! Didnt thought that this can affect the subject...